# How to calculate size of memory

Tags: c++

I have a class Corpus with the following private members

```
private:
vector<Document> documents_;
```

The class Document private members are as follows

```
 private:
      vector<Word> words_;

      // Topic path from the root of the tree to a leaf.
      vector<Topic*> path_;
```

The class Word has the following private members

```
 private:
  int id_;
  int count_;
  int level_;
```

The class Topic has the following private members

```
    private:
  int topic_word_no_;
  // Parent topic.
  Topic* parent_;

  // Children topics.
  vector<Topic*> children_;

  // The tree which this topic belongs to.
  Tree* tree_;
```

and the Class Tree has the following private members

```
private:
  // Depth of the tree.
  int depth_;
  vector<double> eta_;

  // Root topic of the tree.
  // Each node of the tree is associated with a topic.
  Topic* root_topic_;

  // The next id for the following topic.
  int next_id_;
```

How would I calculate the total memory if I have 10 documents in the class Corpus?

Comment: You'll need to take in account that padding can occur for proper alignment. Anyways the minimum size of class Corpus will be the size of `std::vector<Document>` and is independent of the number of Documents strored in the vector.

Comment: `sizeof(Corpus) + corpus.documents_.size() * sizeof(Document) + ...` to start with

Comment: The minimum size needed, or the actual amount of allocated memory? (e.g. `std::vector` is likely to have additional unused capacity allocated in its backing array)

Comment: @Gruffalo Actually, it will be `corpus.documents_.capacity()`, assuming the OP the wants the *total* memory used.

Comment: @Banex: that's correct

Comment: OP also needs to decide what memory associated with a pointer s/he cares about. A pointer has a size that needs to be counted, and may also point to one or many objects which also need to be counted.  Since the example is objects containing objects, containing objects/containers/pointers the logic is recursive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the example is complex, the problem is only partly defined and, even if one was to describe only the principles of an answer (as distinct from providing code, which would take more effort) it would take significant effort to produce an answer that is of little use to others.